# how to repeat result from math.random in javascript?

Tags: javascript

just to clarify my question, i need to generate a 2 digits numbers separately to make it set of 6 like this "12,45,24,63,64,1"

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>lotto picker</title>

 </head>
 <body>


    <p> I can generate you a lotto numbers to bet right now!</p>
    <button id="generateButton">Generate!</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("generateButton").onclick = function() {

                var msg = " ";
                var lottoNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 64) + 1);


                alert(lottoNum);


            }
 </script>
 </body>


</html>
```

Comment: At first, read about the basics of html. Tip: the header is never displayed.

Comment: [<head></head>](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp) Tag doesnt display any information,it describes your html document.You can load some external code for example.Put your code inside `<body></body>` tag.You can create fiddle here in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate 6 2-digit number you need to loop six times. Below is the program to generate 6 2-digit number

```js
document.getElementById("generateButton").onclick = function() {
                var msg = " ";
                for(var i = 0 ;i < 6 ; ++i) {
                var lottoNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 89) + 10;
                msg += lottoNum + ",";
                }
                msg = msg.slice(0, -1);
                alert(msg);
            }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>lotto picker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p> I can generate you a lotto numbers to bet right now!</p>
    <button id="generateButton">Generate!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: it generates 1 digit number

Answer (score 1):

Here `10` to `89` is the desired range.

Where:

`10` is the start number

`89` is the number of possible results `(10 + start (89) - end (10))`

```js
    document.getElementById("generateButton").onclick = function() {
                var msg = " ";                
                for(var i = 0 ;i < 6 ; ++i) {
                var lottoNum = Math.floor(Math.random() *89) + 10;
                msg += lottoNum + ", ";
                }
                msg = msg.slice(0, -1);
                alert(msg);
                }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>lotto picker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p> I can generate you a lotto numbers to bet right now!</p>
    <button id="generateButton">Generate!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: i am sorry if you dont understand my question.... but my point is i want to generate 2 digits of random numbers repeated 6 times

Comment: I changed my answer. Take a look at this. It generates number between 10 to 89. Where:

10 is the start number
89 is the number of possible results (10 + start (89) - end (10))